# Using Summoning Jutsu who has blood of someone who has made a contract?

Tags: naruto

According to [wiki](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Summoning_Technique) in Summoning Technique it is written that:

> It should be noted that 
>   **anyone can summon a contracted animal as long
>    as they have the blood of someone who has made a contract**, the seal of
>   the summoned creature and a source of sufficient chakra that the
>   summon will accept

Means anyone can summon a contracted animal by having blood of someone who has made a contract. So my question is:

Is there any event mentioned in anime or manga which shows this type summoning ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Chapter 363, *Sasuke's Death...!!* (episode 125 of *Shippuden*), Suigetsu summons Manda using Sasuke's blood. This was right after Deidara used his C0 technique.

[image]

Comment: Shouldn't you add a spoiler alert since (I'm pretty sure) a lot of people haven't gotten to (see/read) that point of the story?

Comment: @Ms.Steel: I thought of putting spoiler blocks, but decided against it since this arc is pretty early in the Shippuden series and was, on the contrary, quite sure that majority of the followers have seen/read this part.

Answer (score 4):

You can see this in episode 95 ("Long Time No See: Jiraiya Returns!") and episode 96 ("Deadlock! Sannin Showdown!") of Naruto. In this Kabuto uses Orochimaru's blood to summon Manda.